# question about code comments in book about designing the business layer

Tags: c#

> Thanks all for the help

Hi All,

```
public static List<Order> LoadAll()  
{
    // Load all orders in the table. If too
    // many records, consider exposing this 
    // operation as a plain ADO.NET function.
}
```

What would the "plain ADO.NET function" look like if there were too many records?

Thanks,
rod.

P.S.
The name of the book is:

> Microsoft® .NET: Architecting
>   Applications for the Enterprise

Comment: I have no idea. You should maybe ask the author. There's no industry-wide term "plain ADO.NET function".

Comment: Maybe something like returning some ADO.NET reader object that fetches the orders in batches instead of retrieving all orders and store them in the list? Would make sense if the number of orders is large.

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: See updated OP for name of book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He *probably* means streaming the data from the database via a `DbDataReader` object rather than loading all of the records into an in-memory `List<T>`. You could implement that as an `IEnumerable<T>` and yield return objects based upon the current data record.

Comment: Which would be better done by returning `IQueryable<Order>` anyway.